# Crack RSA with additional information

Tags: rsa

Suppose $N=3953$, Alice encryption key is $e_A = 337$ and bobs is $e_B=23$. Eve happens to know the corresponding decryption keys, $d_A=3385$ and $d_B=2663$. Can I use this information to find the prime factorization of $N$?

Comment: Yes, you can. Given both the public and the private key, you can get the factorization of N. Don't know how, through.

Comment: You even need only one pair $e_A$ and $d_A$.

Comment: [Dan Boneh's paper](http://www.ams.org/notices/199902/boneh.pdf) contains an algorithm (page 205, fact 1).

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an overkill of information, really. We know that $e_A$ and $d_A$ are related by the fact that $e_A d_A \equiv 1 \pmod{\phi(N)}$, normally, and then [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/22388/553) gives an algorithm.

But here we have more info, as both $e_A d_A - 1$ and $e_B d_B - 1$ are multiples of $\phi(N) = (p-1)(q-1)$. We need some multiple of their gcd, that is close to $N$ to get $\phi(N)$. 
Their gcd is 7656, and half of that is 3828, which is probably $\phi(N) = (p-1)(q-1)$.

Now from this you can solve the quadratic equation $(x-p)(x-q) = 0$, because the left hand side is now known: $x^2 - (p+q)x + pq = x^2 + (N - \phi(N) + 1 )x + N = 0$, and $p$ and $q$ follow from the standard formula.

Comment: Actually, it's not necessary true that either of $e_Ad_A-1$ or $e_Bd_B-1$ are multiples of $\phi(N)$; all we know is that they will be multiples of $\lambda(N) = lcm(p-1,q-1)$. This subtlety will prevent straight-forward approaches such as you have outlined from working.  On the other hand, the answer you pointed to will work.

Comment: In most textbooks (that I assumed the problem was from) it is.

Comment: I would suggest you get better textbooks, then (:-).   Or, rather, if the textbooks say "one way to generate $d$ is with $d = e^{-1} \bmod \phi(N)$", well, that's as correct as far as it goes; however that's not a necessary condition.